# How to use typescript + css modules with Laravel Mix

Tags: typescript, webpack, laravel-mix, css-modules

I have a Laravel project with a React + Typescript front end, and I want to load css modules. I've updated my `webpack.mix.js` as follows to try to achieve that:

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.tsx', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/landing.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: /\/js\//,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' }, 
                    { loader: 'css-modules-typescript-loader' }, 
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } } 
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    }
});
```

However, when I try to build (`npm run dev`) the build fails

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-2!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-modules-typescript-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-2!./resources/js/style.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | var api = require("!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
    | ^
  2 |             var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-modules-typescript-loader/index.js!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-2!./style.css");
  3 |
```

It seems, if I'm understanding this correctly, that `css-loader` is being called twice, but I don't know why or how to make that not happen. (I'm not even sure that's what's happening).

Comment: I didn't figure out how to get around this duplication (which I verified is what was happening by logging the eventual config mix was producing). So I just did the obvious and switched to my own webpack config, which this practically already was anyway, and uninstalled `laravel-mix`

Comment: you can try this package https://github.com/Aslam97/laravel-mix-vue-css-modules

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to solve this issue?